# import a CSV file using its URL using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python and i wanted to get csv data from a .csv url to a dataframe in my python script, how do I do it? please help.

I am using Jupyter Notebook on my system(which I opened using Terminal) to write the code.

The following is my code and error message.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv')
```

The error message is long but this is how it starts:

```
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1316                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1317                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1318             except OSError as err: # timeout error
```

Comment: Download the csv file, add it to the same folder and try to read.

Comment: What’s the full traceback and where are you running the script from? Look like you might need to update the root certs on your machine if you’re getting SSL errors for GitHub

Answer (score 1):

I haven't problem with your code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv')
df
country year    pop continent   lifeExp gdpPercap
0   Afghanistan 1952    8425333.0   Asia    28.801  779.445314
1   Afghanistan 1957    9240934.0   Asia    30.332  820.853030
2   Afghanistan 1962    10267083.0  Asia    31.997  853.100710
3   Afghanistan 1967    11537966.0  Asia    34.020  836.197138
4   Afghanistan 1972    13079460.0  Asia    36.088  739.981106
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1699    Zimbabwe    1987    9216418.0   Africa  62.351  706.157306
1700    Zimbabwe    1992    10704340.0  Africa  60.377  693.420786
1701    Zimbabwe    1997    11404948.0  Africa  46.809  792.449960
1702    Zimbabwe    2002    11926563.0  Africa  39.989  672.038623
1703    Zimbabwe    2007    12311143.0  Africa  43.487  469.709298
1704 rows × 6 columns
```

Comment: It doesn’t work for me, i get an error that i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the SSLCertVerificationError, please install this package to avoid this error

```
pip install PyOpenSSL
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to first download the CVS file using `urllib2` library and then pass the result to CSV library to read that file into Python. Here is the suggested code:

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)
```